# Question about closures, memory leaks and scope chain

Tags: javascript, closures

While I've been using closures for a while, I'm still in the fog about a few of things.

1. Is there a difference between passing a globally initialized object as a parameter to the outer and/or innner scope fuctions vs referencing the object directly from the global scope? I ask because I see all 3 implementations in various scripts and tutorials.
2. Would any of these implementations cause memory leaks?
3. Which implementation is best practice?

```
const obj = {
  breakfast: 'Earl Grey',
  lunch: 'croissant',
  dinner: 'Ten Forward'
};

// Example #1 
const closure = () => () => obj.dinner = 'Saurian Brandy';
const test = closure();
test();

console.log( obj );

/*
{
  breakfast: 'Earl Grey',
  lunch: 'croissant',
  dinner: 'Saurian Brandy'
}
*/
```

I don't quite understand why a globally initialized object has to be passed as a parameter since it's already accessible by the outer and inner scopes, but I see the following nonetheless...

```
//#Example #2
const closure = obj => obj => obj.dinner = 'Saurian Brandy';
const test = closure();
test(obj);

console.log( obj );

/*
{
  breakfast: 'Earl Grey',
  lunch: 'croissant',
  dinner: 'Saurian Brandy'
}
*/

//#Example #3
const closure = () => obj => obj.dinner = 'Saurian Brandy';
const test = closure();
test(obj);

console.log( obj );

/*
{
  breakfast: 'Earl Grey',
  lunch: 'croissant',
  dinner: 'Saurian Brandy'
}
*/
```

Clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your global is exposed. Any code can access it. Closures offer the protection of the variable scope; the only code that can access the object is within the function.

Comment: I think this depends on a few things most of which being call site. In example 3 you could define everything, pass the test function to somewhere else in your code where you could then call it and pass in any variable.

Comment: If I remember correctly from school this technique is mainly used when you have a multi step operation. Step 1 outputs x, pass that to your closure function and pass it on to step 2, step 2 outputs y, pass that to test and then your closure can perform z operation on your multi step operation

Comment: "*Which implementation is best practice?*" - neither, they all don't make sense. (#2 and #3 are not even closures, as they don't have free variables). The only case where a closure might be useful would be `obj => () => obj.dinner = 'Saurian Brandy';`

Comment: "*Is there a difference between passing a globally initialized object as a parameter to the outer and/or innner scope fuctions vs referencing the object directly from the global scope?*" - using a function with a parameter only makes sense if you are passing different objects in different calls. If you have only a single object that you ever use the function with, you might as well reference it directly.